# How to save search results in a ListView (Android) in current Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-activity, full-text-search

In my App I have 3 Activities 
1. Search Box Activity (A)
2. ListView Activity to Show Results (B)
3. WebView Acitivity to show single page (C)

A -> B -> C

I use System Back button to go back or have

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

and it show a back button in App.

after successfull single result shown i go back

A <- B <- C

How to save search results in a **ListView** (Android) in **current Activity (B)** so that when I open a **new Activity (C)** by clicking on a ListView Item I can come back and the same search result is showing.

For me the App crashes when I come back from the **newly opened Activity (C)** to the **previous Activity (B)** by pressing **System Back Button**.

I tried many suggestions on different forums and also on Stackoverflow. That include saving data using `onSaveInstanceState();`

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("someVarB", saveMe);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Toast.makeText(this,"Saving Entry = " + saveMe, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("You are in onSaveInstanceState! " + saveMe);}
```

Butt no success. App crashed when I return from Activity C to Activity B.

Please suggest me what to do to solve my problem Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all night different solution but nothing worked.

But here is very simple and 100% working Solutions I found.

```
public void onBackPressed() { 
    finish();
}
```

It will finish **newly opened Activity (C)** and show **previous Activity (B)**

I never needed to save any data. Actually **previous Activity (B)** was not **Stopped** but **Paused** and was already there with everything in it. It just hides when **new Activity (C)** is opened. When we `finish();` n**ewly opened Activity (C)** it is `Stopped();` and previous is shown again Not Recreated.

It may help someone and save his time. Thanks